# How to change the size of a window's surface?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, surfaceview, android-windowmanager

So I know that a `SurfaceView`'s surface size can be changed by calling `setFixedSize()` on the `SurfaceHolder`, but when I try to do the same thing on an arbitrary window, one obtained from an activity, I cannot. Here's the relevant test code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements Callback2 {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().takeSurface(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        arg0.setFixedSize(300, 300);
    }
}
```

This results in the following error log:

> 01-15 23:21:46.111: E/AndroidRuntime(9748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 01-15 23:21:46.111: E/AndroidRuntime(9748): Process: com.example.windowtest, PID: 9748
>
> 01-15 23:21:46.111: E/AndroidRuntime(9748): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: **Currently only support sizing from layout**
>
> 01-15 23:21:46.111: E/AndroidRuntime(9748): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TakenSurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(ViewRootImpl.java:6094)

Where by layout I suppose it means `WindowManager.LayoutParams` which would resize the Window's dimension as well. So is there no way to change the size of a Window's Surface without changing the Window's dimensions? I would think there is, since we can do it with `SurfaceView`, but I'm not sure how.

**Edit**: In addition, the `SurfaceView` `setFixedSize()` call results in a `requestLayout()`, which propagates up to an object that implements the `ViewParent` interface. What is this `ViewParent` object that is getting attached to the `SurfaceView` at runtime? Maybe then the logic behind how the surface buffer is getting resized will be clear.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually possible using NDK's [ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/a-native-window#anativewindow_setbuffersgeometry):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_organization_app_TestActivity_setBufferGeometry(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject surface, jint width, jint height)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "setBufferGeometry(): %p %dx%d", surface, width, height);
    ANativeWindow* window = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, surface);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "setBufferGeometry(): window: %p", window);
    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(window, width, height, AHARDWAREBUFFER_FORMAT_R8G8B8X8_UNORM);
}
```

Java Code:

```
private static native void setBufferGeometry(Surface surface, int width , int height );

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
{
    Log.d( TAG, "surfaceChanged()...");
    setBufferGeometry(holder.getSurface(), 768, 1366);
    /* ... */
```

From the ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry docs:

> Change the format and size of the window buffers.
>
> The width and height control the number of pixels in the buffers, not
> the dimensions of the window on screen. **If these are different than
> the window's physical size, then its buffer will be scaled to match
> that size when compositing it to the screen.**

Comment: link needs updating to here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/a-native-window#anativewindow_setbuffersgeometry
otherwise, a great answer, that has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All of the View-based UI is on a single layer (a/k/a window).  You can't change the surface scaling for a single View; that wouldn't make sense.  You'd have to change the setup for the entire View composition surface, and the framework doesn't want to let you do that.

The SurfaceView's surface is on a separate layer, composited independently, so you have much more freedom to alter its dimensions.

See also: [Android System-Level Graphics](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).

Comment: But consider if I didn't setContentView above, then the activity's window wouldn't have any View attached and yet we still cannot set the backing surface's size. So is there a flag that SurfaceView's separate layer is using that tells the framework that a window has no view attached (thus allowing setFixedSize)?

Comment: The SurfaceView has two parts, the "View" part (which is a transparent place-holder used for the layout), and the "Surface" part (which is a separate layer composited by SurfaceFlinger, and has no Views on it whatsoever).  The surface used by the app framework to show the Views is managed by the framework, and you can't mess with it.

Comment: Yes i understand, and all that framework abstraction is nice, but take a look at the source code. The surface can definitely be messed with for properties other than buffer size, and the surface is not what determines whether such properties can be set. That is determined by the containing Window or SurfaceHolder. Now since both the SurfaceView's separate layer (the "Surface" part) and an arbitrary window I configure have all the same components, i was wondering: what flags tell the framework that no view is attached?